# How to ignore - Error while PROCESSING TOC

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a bash script which restores the tables using `pg_restore`. When I run the script it throws `Error while PROCESSING TOC`. However, the tables were restored successfully. But the `pg_restore` command returns exit status of 1 to the bash.
How can I tell postgres to ignore those TOC errors so that it returns exit status of 0 to the bash.

Here is the full error I get:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC: 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 9368; 2620 14383804      TRIGGER replicate_track_truncate_public_student_trigger auser
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  trigger "replicate_track_truncate_public_student_trigger" for table "student" does not exist
Command was: DROP TRIGGER replicate_track_truncate_public_student_trigger ON  public.student;
```

Comment: You might want to consider fixing the error instead of circumventing the error output. The next time you restore the database it might be a serious error.

Comment: Why is it generating the DROP TRIGGER command in the first place?  If you want to paper over errors rather than fix them, you can add `|| true` to the end of the shell command.

Comment: @jjanes adding `|| true` will always return 0 to bash. In that case if certain tables are not restored because of some genuine errors, it will still return 0 to bash. For eg. If database is not up, connection is not established and if I use `|| true` it will act as connection was successful.